# MongoDb aggregate and group by two fields depending on values

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to aggregate over a collection where a type is given. If the type is **foo** I want to group by the field **author**, if the type is **bar** I want to group by **user**.

All this should happen in one query.

Example Data:

```
{
   "_id": 1,
   "author": {
     "someField": "abc",
  },
   "type": "foo" 
}

{
   "_id": 2,
   "author": {
     "someField": "abc",
  },
   "type": "foo" 
}

{
   "_id": 3,
   "user": {
     "someField": "abc",
  },
   "type": "bar" 
}
```

This user field is only existing if the type is **bar**.

So basically something like that... tried to express it with an `$or`.

```
function () { 
var results = db.vote.aggregate( [ 
   { $or: [ {

      { $match : { type : "foo" } },
      { $group :    { _id : "$author", sumAuthor : {$sum : 1} } } },

      { { $match : { type : "bar" } },
      { $group : { _id : "$user", sumUser : {$sum : 1} } } 
   } ] }
] );
return results;
}
```

Does someone have a good solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it can be done by

```
db.c.aggregate([{
    $group : {
        _id : {
            $cond : [{
                $eq : [ "$type", "foo"]
            }, "author", "user"]
        },
        sum : {
            $sum : 1
        }
    }
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution below can be cleaned up a bit...

For "bar" (note: for "foo", you have to change a bit)

```
    db.vote.aggregate(
        {
            $project:{
                user:{ $ifNull: ["$user", "notbar"]},
                type:1
            }
        },
        {
            $group:{
                _id:{_id:"$user.someField"},
                sumUser:{$sum:1}
            }
        }
    )
```

Also note: In you final answer, anything that is not of type "bar" will have an _id=null

Answer (score 0):

What you want here is the [**`$cond`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) operator, which is a ternary operator returning a specific value where the condition is true or false.

```js
db.vote.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": null,
        "sumUser": { 
            "$sum": {
                "$cond": [ { "$eq": [ "$type", "user" ] }, 1, 0 ]
            }
        },
        "sumAuhtor": { 
            "$sum": {
                "$cond": [ { "$eq": [ "$type", "auhtor" ] }, 1, 0 ]
            }
        }
    }}
])
```

This basically tests the "type" of the current document and decides whether to pass either `1` or `0` to the [**`$sum`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) operation.

This also avoids errant grouping should the "user" and "author" fields contain the same values as they do in your example. The end result is a single document with the count of both types.

Comment: not quite that what I need. I need a document for every author resp. user with their sum

Comment: @koengsen Fair enough. I was mainly looking at your sample which would have resulted in only one document based on the data presented. That and you seemed to be asking for the total counts.